# Texture diffuse not showing up

Tags: texturing

They are both the same menu way do they have different options? How do i get the left options to look like the rights?

[image: Left vs Right?]

Answer (score 3):

Watch out your upper right angle: one is a Cycles material, the second is Blender Internal. They are two completely different render engines, which require different materials.

To switch render engines use this menu:

[image]